# ¿Generar y llamar a consultas de bases de datos antes o dentro de html?

Tags: base-de-datos, estructuras-de-datos, optimización, sql

Pues busqué esta pregunta, pero no encontré ninguna pregunta como esta sobre las consultas de la base de datos solo para el código JavaScript o JQuery. ¿Cuál es la mejor práctica, llamar a las consultas de la base de datos antes de iniciar HTML o dentro del body? (hago consultas des del php que genera el html, es mejor generarlas antes de empezar la etiqueta `<html>` o mejor dentro del `<body>`).

Ya de paso, ¿es mejor llamar a la función para imprimir el código en el lugar deseado o poner la consulta e imprimir directamente dentro del DIV o el elemento que sea? (En caso de ser mejor llamarlo antes, es mejor hacer las consultas y luego en en body poner el echo o el echo ponerlo junto con las consultas y llamar des del DIV con una función).

Espero aprender y optimizar mejor mi sitio web.

Comment: Por lo general debes de mantener los mejor clasificada y reestructuado la infraestructura de tu portal. No mezclar códigos o lenguajes distintos, crea carpetas para tu HTML, otras para tu programación, otras para tu diseño y otras para tu lenguaje SQL. Lo ideal es que manejes funciones dentro de tu HTML las cuales vinculen a tus consultas SQL.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a hacerlo desde el punto de vista del servidor o desde el punto de vista del cliente? ¿Qué lenguaje de servidor usas?

Comment: Desde el punto de vista del servidor, el cliente solo debe manejar el front-end (HTML, CSS; Javascript) toda la lógica de negocio debe hacerse en el lado del servidor con lenguajes como PHP, Python, Java...

Comment: @XBoss, ¿tu comentario hace referencia a mi comentario o hace referencia a la pregunta planteada?

Comment: A tu comentario

Comment: utilizo mysqli y ya divido el contenido y lenguajes en carpetas pero hay consultas que las hago en el propio documento del cliente. Oscar me refiero des del punto de vista del cliente.

Comment: ¿Haces las consultas desde "el HTML"? ¿O desde "el PHP que genera el HTML"? Son dos cosas muy distintas, pero la gente suele confundirlas.

Comment: Des del PHP que genera el HTML. Pero lo que pregunto es que si hago consultas des del php que genera el html, es mejor generarlas antes de empezar la etiqueta <html> o mejor dentro del <body>.

Comment: Y en caso de ser antes, es mejor hacer las consultas y luego en en body poner el echo o el echo ponerlo junto con las consultas y llamar des del DIV con una función.

Comment: Si esas consultas las tienes que hacer seguro, es mejor hacerlas asíncronamente

Comment: eso esta bien saberlo (aunque casi no hay nada de información de mysqli async), pero eso no responde ninguna de mis 2 preguntas.

Comment: @XBoss, recuerda poner un nombramiento para saber a quién te diriges. Por defecto es al autor de la pregunta. Menzezzz, entonces si estás buscando dónde poner tu código PHP para optimizar la carga de la web, da prácticamente igual que pongas el código antes o después ya que los tiempos de acceso a bases de datos y sistemas de archivos suelen ser muy inferiores a las latencias de red al descargar el contenido.